# How to create an "abstract block" in tornado template?

Tags: python, tornado

I want to crate a block in tornado template, this block must be replaced in child template(like an abstract method must be overridden in subclass).

How to implement an "abstract block"?

Answer (score 4):

Why you need such weird thing?

Ok, here are your wheels for the road of programmers' nightmare:

module not_implemented:

```
raise Exception('Not implemented template block')
```

parent template:

```
{% block abstract %}
   {% import not_implemented %}
{% end %}
```

child template:

```
{% extends 'parent.html' %} 
{% block abstract %}{% end %}
```